# Linker error when overriding free in MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker, overriding, free

I'm building a DLL with VS 2013 and I tried to override some functions like `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and `free`.
Everything works except for `free`, MSVC throws me this error:
    error LNK2005 _free already defined in Override.obj

Please note that I'm linking statically to the runtime library and that I added '/nodefaultlib:libcmt.lib /nodefaultlib:libcmtd.lib /nodefaultlib:libc.lib' to the linker command line.

Here's how I overridden those functions:

```
extern "C" {

void *malloc( size_t Size )
{
    return g_pCustomAlloc->Alloc( Size );
}

void *calloc( size_t Elements, size_t ElementSize )
{
return g_pCustomAlloc->CAlloc( Elements, ElementSize );
}

void *realloc( void *Ptr, size_t NewSize )
{
    return g_pCustomAlloc->Realloc( Ptr, NewSize );
}

void free( void *Ptr )
{
    g_pCustomAlloc->Free( Ptr );
}

} // extern "C"
```

Comment: what is g_pCustomAlloc in your code ?

Comment: @ShivarajBhat It's a pointer to a memory allocation class